# Var assignment in sequence diagram

Tags: uml, variables, sequence-diagram

I am trying to represent the function below (PHP function/Symfony2) as a sequence diagram using UML 2.0 and Visual Paradigm:

```
private function getVeevaHcpSync($request, $action, $case)
{   
    set_time_limit(0);
    $mode = "tmb";
    $territory_name= "";
    if($request->getMethod() == "POST")
    {
        $id = $request->get('app_id');
        if($request->get('mode'))
            $mode = $request->get('mode');
        if($request->get('territory'))
            $territory_name = $request->get('territory');
        $reptool_records = $this->getRequestedSyncPost("sync",$request);
    } else {
        $id = $this->getRequested('app_id');
        if($this->getRequested('mode'))
            $mode = $this->getRequested('mode');
        if($this->getRequested('territory'))
            $territory_name = $this->getRequested('territory');
        $reptool_records = $this->getRequestedSync();
    }

    $response = new \stdClass();
    $response->status = FormUtilities::RESPONSE_STATUS_VALID;
    $sync = array();
    $veeva_hcp_ids = array();
    $terr_hcp_ids = array();

    if( ( $salesforceConfig =   $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PDOneBundle:RepappConfig')->findOneBy(array("app_id"=>$id))) )
    {
        $project_id = $salesforceConfig->getProjectId();
        if (isset($territory_name) && !empty($territory_name))
        {
            $terrHcps = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Hcp')->findAllHcpsByTerritory($territory_name,$project_id);
        } else {        
            foreach($reptool_records as $reptool_record)
            {
                $territoryObj = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Territory')->findTerritoryByHcpId($reptool_record->id);
                if (isset($territoryObj[0]) && !empty($territoryObj[0]))
                 {
                    $terrHcps = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('PDOneBundle:Hcp')->findAllHcpsByTerritory($territoryObj[0]->getTerritory(), $project_id);
                    $territory = $territoryObj[0]->getTerritory();
                    break;
                } 
            }
        } 
    }

    $response->sync = $sync;
    $controller_response = new Response( json_encode($response) );
    $controller_response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    return $controller_response;
}
```

But I do not know if I should represent the whole flow or just the significant parts, what would you do? This is how my [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubRuk.jpg) looks like:

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's complete wrong so:

- How can assign function returns to a var and use that var in a conditional?
- How you would do the diagram for this function?

Comment: Variable assignment is too low level of a detail for a sequence diagram.

Comment: @Brandon fine, I get it, if you will made that function in a SD how you will do it? Can you show me an example?

Comment: Assigning something to a variable could be modeled as message-to-self "remember that X is 3" or `rember("x", 3)` or something along the line. You can then use your `x` in a guard condition in `alt` combined fragment. UML Activity Diagrams and UML Interaction Overview Diagrams are more expressive when it comes to showing complex flow with decisions etc. Dig [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/) for explanations and examples

Comment: Personally, I would model the method calls only.  My sequence diagrams tend to mimic the execution stack roughly, but only with interesting method calls (excluding things like getters/setters).